# Difference between WebViewPage.ViewData and @Html.ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just wondering what the actual difference between the `ViewData` that is bound to the MVC view and the `ViewData` that is bound to the `@Html` helper object?

I have written a page and they don't seem to refer to the same thing. Is `ViewData` used anywhere else in the application as another dictionary hidden under the same name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
The `HtmlHelper`'s `ViewData` is based on the view's data. So it has same values upon entering view code (for example, Razor or ASPX page). But you can change these `ViewData`s separately.

It is used same way in `AjaxHelper`.

`RepeaterItem` has it's own ViewData, which is based on the item.

I have not found any use of different `ViewData` anywhere.

**UPDATE:**
`ViewData` and `@Html.ViewData` are different only when you use a strongly typed view. If you use a not strongly typed view, both they are equal as reference. So I think this was done to wrap the `ViewData` into strongly typed `ViewDataDictionary<>`.

---

**SOME INVESTIGATIONS:**

I have taken a look at the decompiled sources and here is what I found.

Let's see, what is @Html.ViewData:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
  public class HtmlHelper<TModel> : HtmlHelper
  {
    private ViewDataDictionary<TModel> _viewData;

    public ViewDataDictionary<TModel> ViewData
    {
      get
      {
        return this._viewData;
      }
    }

    public HtmlHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer)
      : this(viewContext, viewDataContainer, RouteTable.Routes)
    {
    }

    public HtmlHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer, RouteCollection routeCollection)
      : base(viewContext, viewDataContainer, routeCollection)
    {
      this._viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(viewDataContainer.ViewData);
    }
  }
}
```

As we see, the `ViewData` is instantiated from some `viewDataContainer` in `HtmlHelper` constructor.

Let's try to see, how is this connected with the page:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc { 

    public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage {

        // some code

        public override void InitHelpers() {
            base.InitHelpers(); 

            // ...

            Html = new HtmlHelper<TModel>(ViewContext, this);
        } 

       // some more code
    }
}
```

So the current page is the `viewDataContainer`.

So, we see, that a new instance of a `ViewData` dictionary is instantiated for `HtmlHelper` based on the dictionary, which is stored in `View`. The only option, which could make the two be kinda same, if they used same `Disctionary` internally. Let's check that.

Here is `ViewData` constructor:

```
    public ViewDataDictionary(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) 
    {
        if (dictionary == null) { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        } 

        foreach (var entry in dictionary) {
            _innerDictionary.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value); 
        }
        foreach (var entry in dictionary.ModelState) {
            ModelState.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        } 

        Model = dictionary.Model; 
        TemplateInfo = dictionary.TemplateInfo; 

        // PERF: Don't unnecessarily instantiate the model metadata 
        _modelMetadata = dictionary._modelMetadata;
    }
```

As we can see, entries a just copied, but a different underlying `_innerDictionary` is used.

Comment: So is it the same thing or not? If not whats the point why have the MVC team made it this way?

Comment: After some additional investigation, I found out, that `ViewData` and `@Html.ViewData` are different only when you use a strongly typed view. If you use a not strongly typed view, both they are equal as reference. So I think this was done to wrap the `ViewData` into strongly typed `ViewDataDictionary<>`.

Comment: wasted 2 hours on this crap, damn ms and their programmers