# ViewDataDictionary differences

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

What is the difference of `ViewDataDictionary` properties for:

- `HtmlHelper<T>.ViewData` vs `HtmlHelper<T>.ViewDataContainer.ViewData`

Comment: Maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433809/difference-between-webviewpage-viewdata-and-html-viewdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, there's no difference.

`HtmlHelper<T>.ViewData` is set by the constructor (well, more accurately, the private field `_viewData` is set by the constructor, but that's what the public property `ViewData` returns) from the `IViewDataContainer` that is passed into the constructor.

`HtmlHelper<T>` derives from `HtmlHelper`.  `HtmlHelper` has the property `ViewDataContainer`. That is set in the constructor from the `IViewDataContainer` that is passed into the constructor.

Essentially, `HtmlHelper<T>.ViewData` is just a "shortcut" to get to `HtmlHelper<T>.ViewDataContainer.ViewData`

There is one caveat, though. Notice I said *initially* there's no difference.

The `HtmlHelper<T>` constructor sets `_viewData` to a **NEW** instance of a `ViewDataDictionary`, passing in the `IViewDataContainer`'s `ViewData` property.

What that means is that `HtmlHelper<T>.ViewData` is initially a *copy* of `HtmlHelper.ViewDataContainer.ViewData`, but it is not the same instance. The data that the two contain will be the same initially. But if you make changes to one, you're not making changes to the other.